# Scroll a div (containing a table) up one row at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a table containing song lyrics. On average the songs have 30 or so lines, but I don't want them all displayed down the page at once, so I put the table in a div with the property overflow:scroll.

I want to do two things: display 4 or 5 lines (table rows) in the div at one time, and as the song progresses the div scrolls down so the current playing line is at the top of the div.

I'm guessing the code will use the properties scrollTop and offsetHeight but I don't know how to put it all together.

Here's the table: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrGnu/3/)**

```
<div id="divlyrics" class="lyrics">
 <table>  
     <tr id="row_0">
    <td>
     <p id="lyric_0" class="lyric_line">
Song lyrics line 1<br>
     </p>
    </td>
   </tr>     
   <tr id="row_1">
    <td>
     <p id="lyric_1" class="lyric_line">
Song lyrics line 2<br>
     </p>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="row_2">
    <td>
     <p id="lyric_2" class="lyric_line">
Song lyrics line 3<br>
     </p>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="row_3">
    <td>
     <p id="lyric_3" class="lyric_line">
Song lyrics line 4<br>
     </p>
    </td>
   </tr>   
   <tr id="row_4">
    <td>
     <p id="lyric_4" class="lyric_line">
Song lyrics line 5<br>
     </p>
    </td>
   </tr>   
   <tr id="row_5">
    <td>
     <p id="lyric_5" class="lyric_line">
Song lyrics line 6<br>
     </p>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.lyrics{
 font-family:Arial;
 overflow:scroll;
}

.lyric_line{
 border:solid 1px;
 text-align:center;    
}
```

(the real table would at least have 2 rows: 1 row just showing 'Line x' and another row showing the lyrics in 3 different forms: in the song's original language, a transliteration and a translation into another language).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function doScroll(){
   $('#divlyrics').scrollTop($('#divlyrics').scrollTop() + 10);
}

setInterval(doScroll, 500);
```

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/wrGnu/7/

Comment: You will have to adjust some params to get what you need, EX: 10 to the height of a line...

Comment: Thank you. Instead of using 10px (Trinh) or 1px (ama2) I guess I can get the offsetHeight of the first row (row_0) and scroll by that.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the :eq(#) selector suffix to get the row of the table you want, and then scroll to that rows y-position or offset.

It would look Something like this but please note I have not tried/tested this particular code:

```
<div id="scrollContainer">
<table id="scrollTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>etc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var currentRow = 0;
function getRow(rowNum) {
  return parseInt($('#scrollTable tr:eq('+rowNum+')').position().top);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  var end = $('#scrollTable tr').length;
  $('#scrollContainer').animate({height:"100px",overflow:"scroll"},'fast',function() {
    var t = setInterval(function() {
      $('#scrollContainer').scrollTop(getRow(currentRow));
      if (++currentRow >= end) clearInterval(t);
    }, 500);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I used this code in production, it works very nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a shorter version of the one written by Trinh Hoang Nhu. As he used **jQuery** which typically makes code longer and slower.

```
function doScroll(){
   document.getElementById('divlyrics').scrollTop += 10;
}

setInterval(doScroll, 500);
```